# redirection to external pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

I am using windows 7 and  I am new to programming in visual studio and vb.net. I developed a test application and in an event of a button i wanted to redirect to Google.com but i couldn't IIS threw an error 404 not found. I understand that the cause may be the fact that Google is not on my development server but i have used absolute URL and response.redirect method does not work. An insight will do a world of good. Here's the code:

```
 {
    Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles      Menu1.MenuItemClick
        Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com.pk")

    End Sub
 }
```

Comment: I am a bit confused between VB. and CSharp syntax at first sight I do not see anything wrong with the code. Have you tried this same code outside your app in an empty web project?

Comment: Can you try it again? Your code seems to be alright and maybe your internet connection was down while testing.